# How to handle large volume of data in gridview?

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I have large volume of records in my database(70k).How do i handle with this kind of volume data in gridview.

Is there any samples provided for this?

Answer (score 2):

Restrict the GridView to showing 10 or 20 items per page and then rewrite your data access layer so that you can request pages of data from the database.  You can then create your own paging buttons and request the proper page of data as the user clicks on each page.

Allowing the user to enter search criteria to reduce the number of rows returned from the database would also be a good option.

Answer (score 0):

use a proper virtualizing datagrid - not the one coming from Microsoft.

Either do it yourself, or buy (Infragistics, Devexpress, Telerik, thy all can do that).

Comment: Wht is a virtualizing datagrid?

Comment: Googling indicates that a virtualizing datagrid is a control concept for WPF or Silverlight. Not webforms. Can you suggest a better tool for the OP?

Comment: No. Item Virtualization is a CONCEPT. Like architecture it is not specific to a technology. Both Infragistics as well as Telerik ASp.NET webform grids support partial load (paging) with virtualization of the rest on the server.